# Selenium Grid : Windows Service screen resolution

Tags: selenium, windows-services, selenium-grid

I use selenium grid but i have a problem with the screen resolution. My node is install with windows service. 
The service is install on my computer and the current screen of my compuer is 1920x1080
But when mytest is running the max resolution is : 1040/784.
How change this

with the "RemoteWebDriver"
language : c#

Answer (score 1):

Use browser options to set your desired resolution for your tests.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--window-size=1080,1200");
DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(cap);
```

Comment: the same capabilities will work even with remotewebdriver

Comment: DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.Chrome();
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArguments("--window-size=1080,1200");
capabilities.SetCapability(ChromeOptions.Capability, options);
return new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri(""), capabilities);

doesn't work where is the error ?

Comment: Worked for SeleniumGrid